# Multiple RadTileViewItem with differents skin or themes?

Tags: .net, wpf, telerik, themes

Is it possible to have multiple RadTileViewItem with different skins in the same RadTileView?

Note: The application is "submitted" to a large Metro Skin type through the instructions in VB.NET:

```
     StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = New MetroTheme
     RadSpellChecker.WindowSettings.Theme = StyleManager.ApplicationTheme
```

In advance, thanks for the help you can give me ...

Answer (score 0):

You can apply styles to the **RadTileViewItems** object and have all of them share the same style.
However, if you want to apply a different style to a specific  all you can do is change certain UI-related properties (such as HeaderStyle) for that **RadTileViewItem**. See [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/allmembers_t_telerik_windows_controls_radtileviewitem.html) the complete list of properties.

Also, [this node](http://www.telerik.com/forums/604424-radtileviewitem-style) on Telerik forums might help.